# Can not import images to react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

Hello I am  new to React and I have been tryin to display some images, but I get the following error.

```
   /src/components/rook.png:1
�PNG


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/home/gecf/Projects/reactTests/chess/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/gecf/Projects/reactTests/chess/src/components/Tile.js:2:1)
```

My code which tries to import an image is shown below:

```
import logo  from './rook.png';
```

My file structure is src/components/tile.js  and src/components/rook.png.

My webpack.config.js can be seen below:

```
  module.exports = {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|gif|jpg|png)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
            use: 'file-loader',
          },
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    };
```

I have tried to require the url as well but the same error in both cases.

Comment: Are you not using create-react-app? Also, webpack 4 or 5?

Comment: no i am not using create-react-app. I followed a tutorial where it didn't require me to do so. as for webpack i am using webpack 5.

Answer (score 0):

Always keep first letter of any component capital

```
import Logo  from './rook.png';
```

Comment: Why is that exctly?

Comment: Convention, also many components have same name as html elements, 
so to avoid those errors

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but that wasn't the cause of the problem. I believe to be something with the structure of the folders but i  can't figure out what it is.